# Attach filtered file to displayed email then clear filter

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

I can filter the active sheet to a specified category, send it as an attachment, then clear the filters.

Due to company registry settings, manually changing to not auto-block sending emails from Excel automatically reverses after a few hours.

It would be onerous to instruct users to manually change registry settings every time they update the file. It would be easier to use `EmailItem.Display` and have them click "send".

This has the drawback of sending the attachment without the category filter, perhaps because Outlook updates the attachment as long as both Outlook and Excel are open(?) and the macro clears the filter after generating the email and attachment.

```vb
Sub SendEmail_CATEGORY()

Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Source As String
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'SortFilter

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$CG$1933").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="CATEGORY"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "AR5:AR1933"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


EmailItem.To = "hello1@gmail.com; hello2@gmail.com"
    'To cc an email address
EmailItem.CC = "hello3@gmail.com; hello4@gmail.com"
    'To BCC an email
'EmailItem.BCC = "username@government.gov"
EmailItem.Subject = "Update to File: See filtered attachment"


'Code to attach current workbook to email

Source = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    'Defines "Source" as the current workbook (note the "Dim" line earlier in the code)
EmailItem.Attachments.Add Source
    'Attaches "Source," defined in prior line


'HTML code for email body

EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hello," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "This is an email to inform you of an update to the Spreadsheet" & _
vbNewLine & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
"Regards," & "<br>" & _
"The Team"


EmailItem.Display
'EmailItem.Display to just pull up a draft without sending; EmailItem.Send to send email if permissions allow


'Clear Sort/Filter macro

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$CG$1933").AutoFilter Field:=3
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "B5:B1933"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

`EmailItem.Send` maintains the filters in the attachment. I assume because sending happens before clearing the filters.

One possibility would be to exclude the "Clear Sort/Filter" and put in a "clear filters" button in the workbook, but how could I maintain the filters in the email attachment while still clearing the filters in the live file in the same macro?

Comment: Perhaps you may "saveas" the file in the temp folder and then attach it as an independant file to overcome this. As an OT, if you have found the registry that does that, you may use something like [this](https://vba-corner.livejournal.com/3054.html) to do it within VBA, just set the key as a const string, on a side note: could you comment this registry key location? Another way to avoid the hassle for the user is the following: after the mail has been  displayed use the send command, it shouldn't interfer since the policy likely is to avoid automatically mail sending on the background

Comment: @Sgdva I don't think I can fix the registry issue through VBA -- it's under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\security and then "prompttosend." The temp "saveas" is a good workaround, though, and adding that allowed me to keep the filtered versions by putting the "save" commands before the attach/unfilter commands. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use the [SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) methods to get a copy of the file saved and then attach the file from the location saved. So, before getting the `FullName` property value of the `Workbook` class save your changes:

```
'Code to attach current workbook to email

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filePath ' to save to a specific path 
EmailItem.Attachments.Add filePath
```

> I assume this is because sending the email/attachment happens sequentially before clearing the filters in the code, as was intended.

Having a separate copy of the filtered workbook attached ca solve this problem.